# Understanding copyright field in the iTunes Connect app submission

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm searching the Apple documentation to try to answer this question, but without success. Hope someone of could give me a "safe" reply...

I'm testing an app that I'd like to submit to the App Store for free. During form filling I saw a copyright field that seems to be required. obviously I did not protect my app with any copyright, so I was wondering how should I correctly fill that field?

Unfortunately I'm a little bit anxious about legal details, and I don't want to make something of illegal or similar.

I know that many of you submit "every day" app on the App Store, so I hope to get some help from you...

Thank you very much.

PS: I'm an individual developer, so no company. I suppose that during the first phase of app adding I do not need to select Company Name (that it cannot be changed in the future).

Thanks...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are not planning on doing some sort of DBA or possibly creating an LLC, then you can always just specify the copyright under your own name.

*Just ensure **the text is preceded by a year** (in case of a Person) or, the year the rights were obtained (in case of a Company).*

For Example: **2016 Johnny Bravo**

Below is a screenshot (from *App Store Connect* providing Apple's instruction on how to go about a *Copyright*) for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Didn't really work! Still shows the same error:
`You must provide copyright information for the app you are adding.`

Comment: I can't see this "copyright" field anywhere in the app section of the App Store Connect... where is it ?

Comment: It is under Marketing URL section. I also spent some time to find that box.

Comment: In case someone is still trying to figure out where the copyright field is, you need to enter "App Store Connect" website, "My Apps", click on your App, and then do not click anything else. If you click by mistake any of the left toolbar menu items (like "App information" under "General"), in order to get back to that page, you need to click again the tab "App Store" on the top bar. Usability sometimes is a relative concept.

Answer (score 4):

For developers in Canada, the Canadian Intellectual Property Office states the following:

> Although copyright in a work exists automatically when an original work is created, a certificate of registration is evidence that your creation is protected by copyright and that you, the person registered, are the owner. It can be used in court as evidence of ownership.

ref: http://www.cipo.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/cipointernet-internetopic.nsf/eng/h_wr00003.html?OpenDocument